# Long GPU frames – Chrome devtools performance monitor

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, webgl, regl

I'm running into an issue with WebGL in Google Chrome (61.0) with really long frames that occur around once every 60-90 seconds on my machine. Devtools logs these frames as GPU activity, but what is actually causing these frames to be long is opaque to me. The app is using [REGL](https://github.com/regl-project/regl) and updating attribute buffers every frame with `subdata`. I'm looking for insight into what could be causing these long frames, and how to move forward debugging them, as Chrome's devtools provide no details about [GPU frames](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#gpu).

This issue does not occur with Safari 11.0

After further investigation it seems related to use of the `ANGLE_instanced_arrays` extension. This issue does not occur when disabling instancing and drawing each instance with a separate draw call.

[image: Long GPU frame]

Comment: Did you tryed to run an empty webgl context, with only a clear() call to see if the problem remain ?

Comment: @Sedenion if none of the geometry is drawn, the issue does not occur.

Comment: do you use requestAnimationFrame for drawing? Does this issue occur in other(older/newer) versions of chrome?

Comment: You could try using [about:tracing](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool).

Comment: Can you add a little more description about how you root-caused the issue?

Comment: @KayceBasques I have not yet isolated the particular set of circumstances that cause this bug, other than relating to use of the `ANGLE_instanced_arrays` extension. I have not been able to reproduce it with simplified examples, so for now I'm moving forward without instancing and will try to debug further when I have time.